# Download multiple .csv from url in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have multiple `.csv` datasets and I want to upload them and save them with different names. Many thanks in advance.

```
casualty_2005 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2005-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2006 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2006-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2007 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2007-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2008 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2008-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2009 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2009-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2010 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2010-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2011 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2011-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2012 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2012-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2013 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2013-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
casualty_2014 <- read.csv("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2014-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv", header=T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked many times, create a vector of names/links, then read in all files in a `lapply` loop.
Note that `read.csv`'s default is `header = TRUE`.

```
url_fmt <- "https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/%04d-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
url_years <- 2005:2014
url_vec <- sprintf(url_fmt, url_years)
df_list <- lapply(url_vec, read.csv)
names(df_list) <- url_years

head(df_list[[1]])       # first file, top 6 rows
head(df_list[["2005"]])  # same file
head(df_list$`2005`)     # same file
```

---

### Edit

After reading [doctshind s  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400437/8245406), I realized that the question is asking how to *download* the files, not how to *read* them.

The instructions on setting a new directory are optional.

```
#old_dir <- getwd()
#setwd('~/tmp')

lapply(url_vec, function(x) download.file(x, destfile = basename(x)))
list.files(pattern = '\\.csv')
# [1] "2005-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [2] "2006-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [3] "2007-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [4] "2008-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [5] "2009-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [6] "2010-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [7] "2011-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [8] "2012-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
# [9] "2013-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"
#[10] "2014-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv"

#setwd(old_dir)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fully working code with explanations:

```
# List of File URLs
urlist <- list("https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2005-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2006-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2007-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2008-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2009-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2010-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2011-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2012-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2013-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv","https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/2014-gla-data-extract-casualty.csv")
setwd("~/so")
#for loop to select each url and store them
for (i in 1: length(urlist)) {
#define path to download
#get filename from the url path
destfile<-basename(urlist[[i]])
#download current file
download.file(urlist[[i]]), destfile)
}
```

Comment: Upvote but: 1) `setwd` only once outside the `for` loop; 2) instead of `paste0(urlist[i])`, use `urlist[[i]]`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, updated. May be useful when needed to create subfolders programmatically.